# how to extract Elements in NSMutable Dictionary Array

Tags: ios, dictionary, nsmutablearray

my server sends me an response in hierarchy way i do no how to grab the  value from that

> **here my sample response :**

```
  {
    id = "-1";
    result =         (
                    {
            keyname = "Warranty Expiry Date";
            value = "06-14-2017";
        }
    );
},
    {
    id = "-1";
    result =         (
                    {
            keyname = Owner;
            value = "";
        }
    );
},
    {
    id = "-1";
    result =         (
                    {
            keyname = Model;
            value = "";
        }
    );
},
    {
    id = "-1";
    result =         (
                    {
            keyname = "Price $";
            value = 1000;
        }
    );
},
    {
    id = "-1";
    result =         (
                    {
            keyname = Vendor;
            value = "";
        }
    );
},
    {
    id = "-1";
    result =         (
                    {
            keyname = "Purchase Date";
            value = "";
        }
    );
}
)
```

> **here is sample Java code how they extracted the values**

```
   Hashtable htAttrs = (Hashtable) editedAttrHash.get(assItmId);
        if (htAttrs != null) {
            Set<String> keys = htAttrs.keySet();
            for (String deAttr : keys) {
                xmlSerializer.startTag("", "attribute");
                xmlSerializer.attribute("", "keyname", deAttr);
                xmlSerializer.attribute("", "value", 
      htAttrs.get(deAttr).toString());
                xmlSerializer.endTag("", "attribute");
            }
        }
```

i need to do no how to from this structure past one day i am blocked here anyone can fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

How to extract values from nsmutablearray?If it is really nsmutablearray object, then extract the values is simple.

For example, to get id of first element:

```
NSString firstId = response[0][@"id"]
```

But it seems, like for now, it is just a json object. So, you should serialize it to nsarray object first.

Comment: NSMutableArray *parsedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];                               https://www.appcoda.com/tag/nsjsonserialization/ try this tutorial to better understand JSON.